# Separate react app builds for public site and admin panel

Tags: reactjs, build, create-react-app

I’m working with a react app (CRA) that will be public to endusers, and additionally includes an admin panel to config it. I want to have only one app project, but two isolate builds that include only needed parts to deploy (public site over internet; admin panel over intranet). What is the best way to do it?

Comment: I think deploying the whole application should not be an issue, lazy load the pages the pages that are required when they are called ,would be a better approach than  not deploying them(Unless your Intranet  has like mbs of hardware support ,which i doubt). Other than that , for admin panel you could just have a authorization check anytime any tries to visit it ,after authentication is done , based off of the authorization show them an option/button to access the admin panel.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I agree with you, but It’s a customer requirement that admin panel must be protected to only access from intranet... And I would like to maintain only one app, if it allow me to generate two isolated deployments.

Comment: API is what makes a server talk to another server , ReactJS has no role to play in that .So, making 2 different deployment makes no difference , it makes it inefficient to certain extent  .

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'two isolated deployments' ,  as far as I know , build would generate 1 build for entire application and not subparts.

Comment: As far I know, if I deploy the admin panel only on intranet, we are protecting login page and resources of admin panel to only access users through intranet. I’m missing something?

Comment: Sure, you are right . I was talking about authorization if a single application were to be used and deployed. Nevertheless, since if you won't upload it ,it would be great from a security perspective than having to determine the authorization each time/ making an authentication for users just for the sake of admin panel.